# Apply character vector in double quotes to a variable as individual characters in double quotes separated by commas in R

Tags: r, variable-assignment

I have the following in a data frame:

```
df <- "s1, s2, s3"
```

I would like to assign it to a variable like this:

```
scafhold <- df
```

But the output has to be:

```
scafhold

"s1", "s2", "s3"
```

I have seen tips on using shQuote, but it only works for output and not assigning to a variable.

Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT!!

Just to sum up. I want this:

```
df <- "s1, s2, s3"
```

To be applied like this:

```
df <- c("s1", "s2", "s3")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the strsplit function:

```
strsplit(df, ",")[[1]]
```

should do what you want

Comment: You don't need the stringr package to do this. Just use `strsplit`